# How do I activate a Boolean from one scene using AnimationPlayer from another in Godot?

Tags: game-development, godot, gdscript

I have three scenes: `Main`, `Player`, and `Crop`.

My main scene has the tilesets and a few other child nodes linked (including Player and Crop).

My player scene has a Sprite2D and an AnimationPlayer

My crop scene has a Sprite2D.

Inside my `Crop` scene I have a script that has one variable and one function.

```
@export var is_watered: bool = false

func _process(_delta):
    if is_watered:
        $Sprite2D.texture=ResourceLoader.load(image)
```

`is_watered` is just a Boolean while the `_process` function changes the image of the Crop to its next stage.

Inside my `Player` scene I have an `AnimationPlayer` that has an animation called `water_down`. Also inside the Player scene there's a function called `water()`.

```
func water():
    is_watered = true
```

But because the Player and Crop nodes are different scenes it didn't recognize what `is_watered` is. How can I change the Boolean inside of `Crop` to true while using an AnimationPlayer from the `Player` scene? I tried emitting a signal but that too only connects to nodes inside the same scene.

Comment: Assuming you do not want Player to always water all Crop, you need a way to get a reference to the Crop you want to water from Player. My suggestion would be to use collisions to find it, but as per your description these objects are just sprites, so they have no physics. I do not know if you want to solve this by other means. Once the player has a reference to the crop, it can water it (which can either be triggered by the AnimationPlayer or not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a separate script that is autoloaded and pass variables through that.
You would save the variable in the autoloaded script and then whenever you want to access it you would just call sciptName.variableName instead of just variableName.

**For example, in your case:**

1. Create another script called `Data_transfer`.
2. Set that script as an autoloaded script in Project>Project Settings>AutoLoad.
3. Create a variable in the new script: `var is_watered: bool = false`.
4. Change the initial variable declaration in the `Crop` script to use the `Data_transfer.is_watered` var:
   `@export var is_watered: bool = Data_transfer.is_watered`
   This will allow you to continue to be able to use the `@export` part of the variable, but since changing it doesn't change the Data_transfer variable you will have to have something like: `Data_transfer.is_watered = is_watered` when the script is loaded like in the `_ready()` method. Otherwise, the value of the export won't be used.
5. Change the rest of the `Crop` script to use the `Data_transfer.is_watered` variable instead of `is_watered`.
6. Change the `Player` script to use `Data_transfer.is_watered` instead of `is_watered`.